Convergence of expectation of random variables
I'm stuck on the following question:
Given $(X_n)$ is a sequence of integrable random variables converging almost surely to an integrable random variable $X$, show that $E(|X-X_n|)\to 0$ if and only if $E(|X_n|)\to E(|X|)$.
I know that the forward direction is relatively straightforward via the triangle inequality. For the backward direction, though, I'm stuck. I've tried decomposing $X=X^++X^-$ and trying to compare the expectation of that with the same decomposition for $X_n$, but I'm not sure how to combine the two expectations into one. Apparently I'm supposed to invoke Fatou's lemma, too, and I can't see how that comes into play here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Hint: Start with DCT on  $E(|X|-|X_n|)^{+}$
